# eval could not access variable in function scope

Tags: function, julia, eval

In the MnWE (Minimal not Working Example) below, when I called test(2), I got the error:

> ERROR: UndefVarError: var2 not defined  in test at ./none:6

How to solve this situation without using global variable var1 and var2. In my real situation, var1 and var2 are two lengthy matrices and needed only once to determine a variable s1. Using them as global variables seems ugly (and ineffective), doesn't it?

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
function test(arg)
var1=10
var2=100
s="var$arg"
s=symbol(s)
@eval($s)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval` always evaluates expression in global scope of the current module, thus variables defined inside a function are not in this scope.

Personally I would use a tuple, a vector or a dictionary in such a case as you present. For instance here is the code using `Dict`:

```
function test(arg)
    var1=10
    var2=100
    d = Dict(1=>var1, 2=>var2)
    d[arg]
end
```

And here with a `Tuple` (and a bit more terse):

```
test(arg) = (10, 100)[arg]
```

If `var1` or `var2` were expensive to create then you can use the following pattern:

```
function test(arg)
    arg == 1 && return rand(10^7)
    arg == 2 && return rand(10^6)
    throw(ArgumentError("wrong value of arg ($arg)"))
end
```

in which case only the code that is relevant gets executed. You can achieve the same effect using the above two methods if you wrap generation of `var1` and `var2` in a function, e.g.

```
var1() = rand(10^7)
var2() = rand(10^6)
test(arg) = (var1, var2)[arg]()
```

Comment: Great. Thank you for your solution.